# Writing a custom widget set on top of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, flash, design-patterns, canvas

I need to build a custom widget set on top of the canvas element. This is for a very specific problem domain (handling audio and text in an integrated fashion) so using an existing widget set is out of the question.

The resulting application centers around a [Zooming User Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zooming_user_interface) on top of which our custom widgets are to be placed.

What are some **standard approaches**, **pitfalls** and **design patterns** to be aware of when writing a widget set from scratch?

I imagine that a lot of valuable experiences in this field will not be with the canvas element and HTML5 in particular since it's relatively young. But, of course, any answers that focuses specifically on canvas and javascript will get extra unicorn points.

I also imagine that a lot of experience in this field comes from rather heavy handed OO approaches. The [GOF-book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) deals with GUIs extensively. To what extent are their approaches applicable in a more functionally oriented language like javascript?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add the "flash" tag, since I imagine that to be a community that gathered experience in exactly this domain for several years.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't satisfy your request, but I can share my experience in a similar developement with canvas and javascript.

I logically divide code in 3 parts (come kind of MVC of my scenario): initial setup with data collection, event listeners (mouse move, click, wheel etc), drawing functions. The architecture works well, as the fact that I don't have to modify it adding features.

I use the main common rules of programming as: good code design, document the code, don't do tricks (js offers a lot of tricks), test what you are doing.

I use javascript "as it is" with OOP, using singleton pattern (http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript); google closure library help me to document the code properly - because I need to compile it in advanced mode (https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3) but even without any framework you can write good structured code in js.
So the answer to your final question is "yes, you can do it even in a poor structured language like js".

The main problem I found was test it, you can do only manually, I mean setup an automatic tool, for me was not enough.